# "Four-star verbal commits"

Tags: sentence-structure, nouns, parsing, nominalization

> Early in the morning, the Ducks signed four-star verbal commits Jalen Hall and Isaah Crocker. ([source](https://www.oregonlive.com/recruiting/index.ssf/2018/02/devon_williams_nations_no_16_p_1.html))

I find this sentence very strange and difficult to parse. Is "commit" being used as a noun, with "four-star" and "verbal" as modifiers? "Commit" seemingly doesn't have a noun usage. Is "verbal" an adjective or a noun (which would mean verbal commitment)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess that **commit** is being used as a noun is correct. It's a colloquial way to refer to a high school athlete who makes a commitment to attend a particular college.

A **verbal commit** is an athlete who has made a verbal (and therefore non-binding) commitment.

If you read about, or watch, college football or basketball, you will hear these terms quite often. Otherwise, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is a kind of metonym.

[Compare](http://publiclibrariesonline.org/2018/09/the-opioid-crisis-and-administering-narcan-in-libraries/):

> We saw many **overdoses** in the park.

The individual is referred to via the verb for what they have done.